# Problem running Ajax in Wordpress

Tags: plugins, ajax

**FIXED**

I changed this:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'pfxconversion', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'function.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_localize_script( 'pfxconversion', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_pfxconversion', 'pfxconversion_callback' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_pfxconversion', 'pfxconversion_callback' );
```

to this:

```
add_action ('wp_print_scripts', 'widget_logic_js_fx', 1);

function widget_logic_js_fx() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'purefx-currency-converter', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'function.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_localize_script( 'purefx-currency-converter', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_pfxconversion', 'pfxconversion' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_pfxconversion', 'pfxconversion' );
```

wp_print_scripts is what we we're missing :-)

Comment: @Jared I'll bare that in mind in future, still getting used to how everything works here :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1: the codex recommends enqueing all scripts and styles on the wp_enqueue_scripts() hook.  this won't solve the problem, but is good practice.

2: i think that all the data that goes INTO the php function is wrapped up in $_POST.  which is sent by the .ajax call.  so it doesn't look like you are sending any data other than the action name and it doesn't look like you are properly decoding the data in the PHP file.

i'd start out changing:

```
function pfxconversion () {
  echo "bacon"; exit();
}
```

just to ensure that you are talking to the ajax function.  that part looks correct to me though.

what kind of info are are sending?  some form data?  you'll need to serialize that and include it in the ajax call.

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

```
jQuery("#convert").click(function () {

     jQuery.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
       data: action='pfxconversion&bacon=hellyes',
       success: function(data){

       jQuery('#results').show();
       //Put received response into result div
       jQuery('#results').html(data);
       }
     });
});
```

then on the php side we can get at the post data like this:

```
function pfxconversion () {
      $data = $_POST;
      echo $data['bacon'];
      exit();
    }
```

in theory that should echo out the "hell yes" we set earlier.

you're probably sending a form in which case you'd tack on $('#formID').serialize() like so

```
var formdata = $('#formID').serialize();
```

then your data line in the ajax call would look like:

```
data: formdata + 'action=pfxconversion',
```

since you didn't post what type of info you were trying to send (the HTML) I didn't go ahead and do that, but hopefully you get the gist from my example.

---

EDIT:

so i took a look at admin-ajax.php and you can see 2 things.  first, if the user is not logged in it will try to run

do_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_' . $_REQUEST['action'] );

this action doesn't fire if you are logged in.... which i am on my local install where i am testing this.

so to ensure that this works for BOTH logged in and logged out users we need to add the action to both wp_ajax_ and wp_ajax_nopriv_

secondly, a zero response means that it admin-ajax.php went through all its own switch cases, and didn't find an action.

```
default :
    do_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_GET['action'] );
    die('0');
    break;
endswitch;
```

that's the endtail of the code.... what it means for us is that it isn't finding the action name.

so with that i made some tweaks and i am now getting a response:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {     
    $("#convert").click(function () { 

            var formdata = $('#conversionform').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
            data: 'action=pfxconversion&' + formdata,
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            success: function (resp) { 
                console.log(resp);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });     
});
```

and on the php side:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_pfxconversion', 'pfxconversion_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_pfxconversion', 'pfxconversion_callback' );

function pfxconversion_callback () {
    print_r($_POST);
    exit();
}
```

that should show an array of values from the form in your console... which means you're now talking to the callback function successfully through ajax.

ps- you can add a hidden input with the action to the form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="pfxconversion" />
```

and then it'll be pulled in automatically by serialize() and you won't need to concatenate the string in the .ajax call

//edit

```
function add_my_scripts(){
wp_enqueue_script( 'pfxconversion', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'function.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_localize_script( 'pfxconversion', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','add_my_scripts');
```

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to respond, that all makes perfect sense so i'll have a bash at implementing your recommendations. I am indeed processing form data.

Comment: outside the ajax call

Comment: So now i'm getting -1 output and looking at firebug it's only picking up the amount and from POST but not the to. I can't for the life of me see any problem with it! Any ideas?

Comment: you have your add_action syntax messed up.  please see my edits.  it should take the form: add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ACTION-NAME-IN-AJAX-CALL', 'FUNCTION-NAME-IN-PHP' );

Comment: Many thanks again, that was a really big help and i certainly understand how Wordpress handles Ajax a lot better, however i'm still getting a -1 output, ah the joys of debugging :-)

Comment: can you edit to show what your code looks like now?  and take a look at wp-admin/admin-ajax.php that will show you the possible places the code might die and output a -1

Comment: Thanks so much, your help us greatly appreciated. I've edited the original post with my current code. After removing and re-adding my widget i'm now getting "0" response in the console.

Comment: i'm kind of stumped now. a zero response pretty much means it can't find your action OR you forgot to exit/die your action, but it looks right and works on my end.  how are you enqueuing?  is this live somewhere?

Comment: and this is hacky, but go through admin-ajax.php and everywhere that it says die('0'); change that to something unique die('reason for fail'); and see if that helps you pinpoint where the failure is. obvi, undo everything when you're done b/c hacking core is frowned on

Comment: Thanks again, iv'e just noticed that when i view the source code the admin-ajax.php url is been escaped, see latest edit.

Comment: Also getting a -1 output in console now...

Comment: mine is escaped out too. this has to be something ridiculous b/c i've copied your code and it works.  do you have any other scripts/plugins running?  did you try temporarily putting more using error codes in admin-ajax.php ?  -1 usually means the action isn't set.

Comment: Thanks for your continued help, i finally got to the bottom of it. See my last edit!

Comment: i had that in my answer all along! well at least since yesterday... and on the wp_enqueue_scripts hook which is the advised hook.  facepalm. :)  glad you got it sorted.