# How to post form in ajax mode and handle it in wordpress

Tags: plugin-development, ajax

currently I can only do it in a normal non-wordpress way.

So, does wordpress provide a solution for this circumstance?

Comment: Please click the [tag:ajax] and search through the answers.

Comment: i answered that here too: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42159/problem-running-ajax-in-wordpress/42161#42161

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the preferred method of writing AJAX-enabled plugins?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9231/whats-the-preferred-method-of-writing-ajax-enabled-plugins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does, have you look at Bainternet's solution [to this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9231/whats-the-preferred-method-of-writing-ajax-enabled-plugins/9236#9236) and my answer [to this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37202/ajax-and-autocomplete)?

To summarise, you need to post the request to the WordPress' admin-ajax url. If the ajax is for use on the admin-side then this url should already be available as the javascript variable  `ajaxurl`. If this is for use on the front-end then you'll want to get the admin url:

```
<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>
```

inside your javascript file (see my solution linked above). WordPress then files the following actions:

```
//for logged in users only 
add_action('wp_ajax_MY_ACTION', 'my_ajax_function');

//for non-logged in users 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_MY_ACTION', 'my_ajax_function');
```

Where `MY_ACTION` is the action sent with the AJAX request. You can hook the function that deals with the request, (in this example `my_ajax_function`) onto the appropriate hook(s). This function should echo the response.

For more information see the above answers, and the [Codex on Ajax in WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX).